# Android Studio doesn't open files

Tags: android, android-studio

I have cloned Google's Sunflower project from [here](https://github.com/android/sunflower). Eventually, I had to install some plugins and I could build and run the project. The app works fine. But when I try to open files it doesn't open:
[image]

That progressBar just keeps rolling and rolling. I have tried to open other files, nothing has changed. I have restarted Android Studio and the computer, still the same. What should I do?

Comment: First, try opening other projects to check if the same happens with all of them. If you have the same issue, you should open Android Studio and go to `File > Invalidate Caches / Restart`. If this doesn't solve the issue, I suggest deleting and re-installing Android Studio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem, one of the plugins the project has made me install, namely **Markdown** was the reason. It had some problems with it, so I disabled it and now everything is OK